# Responsive layout, boxes repositioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a site for a college assignment.
I am trying to make it responsive, however while resiznig the window, the boxes in the "upcoming occasions" and "all year around" sections position themselves fairly oddly. It happens at around a width of 990px. They are simply styled at 32% of the container so I can't seem to figure out how its doing this, shouldnt it just stay split into the 3?
http://www.remotegoatdesign.com/sayhey/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Suggest you read yourself in to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). Its a free to use responsive Framework. You should learn the basics of responsive Webdesign befor trying to do so.

Well lets try to fix your Problem ;)

```
.occasionblocks {
    display: block; /* not inline-block */
    float: left; /* add this */
}
.title {
    clear:left; /* add this */
}
```

But there are also other Problems in your css should i fix them too for you?

Happy to help

Comment: Thats perfect thank you! What other problems did you notice?I know the footer is misbehaving a little.

Comment: The left diebar is having troubles because it has `.sidebar { width: 15%; }`, that leads to the error. (have to get in the train), i'll tell you how to fix it

Comment: I see, could that maybe be fixed through another media query?

Comment: Well when is it due? There are so many thing in your css invalid or unessessary. we should switch to chat, this is going to be a long one.

Comment: If you dont want to chat and want to only make the really nessesary changes, i totally respect that. I am making a fiddle for your website right now :) will add the link bit later.

Comment: I would appreciate a chat if you really don't mind it, how do we chat on here? Also wow, thank you! I really appreciate it. :) It is due on monday, although I know I could get it done I would very much appreciate the advice of someone who knows how to mark up more efficiently.

Comment: I don't seem to have enough reputation to initiate a chat on here.

Comment: Here is a little start http://jsfiddle.net/PK2CF/2/ (don't be shocked by the colors ;D) In this example you can see the grid system in implemented (is like that of bootstrap) i hope you can see the improvements in the sidebar by adjusting the size, the content also adjusts to fit the new, smaller windowsize

Comment: Thats definitely interesting! the grid does definitely seem to save a lot of time. Im guessing I could just use a media query then to change the content from 4 to 3, then 2 by just adding new classes?
Its helping me see where I am bloating my CSS for definite.

Comment: Yes that is the plan. the md in the classname stands medium, witch is the screensize. you should make a media query (normal breakpoint is 992px for tablet) and there you could say the size of col-sm-6 is 50% and then add this col-sm-6 to your div where you got col-md-3 or whatever you want :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Assistance is much appreciated, if I had enough reputation I would upvote you but all I have is gratitude :P

Comment: Well what you can do is accept this answer as the right answer ;)